# Interchange contents of variables?

Tags: python, variables, syntax

How would I interchange the contents of variables A and B?

```
temp = A
B = A
A = temp
```

The following code doesn't work. I'm not sure how to fix it. I must not understand python syntax or variables correctly.

Comment: What you have is effectively: `temp = B = A; A = temp`. How is `temp` a temporary store of `A` if the value of `A` doesn't change ?

Answer (score 9):

Python provides particularly elegant syntax for swapping variables:

```
A, B = B, A
```

Answer (score 3):

Erm...

```
temp = A
A = B
B = temp
```